# Magento - Display Belvg Color Swatch attribute on Out-Of-Stock products

Tags: javascript, php, html, magento, zend-framework

I need to know how to display attributes for products when they become **Out-Of-Stock**.
Attributes like:

```
 - colour
```

Currently I use Belvg Color Swatch Pro extension and i'm not able to activate this setting. I found on their presentation page for this plugin "Swatches of out-of-stock products can be set to be displayed.". But in Magento extension panel I can't see this feature.

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to contact Belvg Support?